# FALTAL ERROR PHP & SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estoy tratando de crear un formulario en php con conexión con sql como BD, me sale el siguiente fatal error:

> : Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_query(): Argument #3 ($result_mode) must
> be of type int, string given in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\login-form\registrar.php:22 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\login-form\registrar.php(22):
> mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO dat...', 'INSERT INTO
> dat...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\login-form\index.php(59):
> include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\login-form\registrar.php on line 22

Este es el codigo de registrar.php:

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    if (
        strlen($_POST['name']) >= 1 &&
        strlen($_POST['email']) >= 1 &&
        strlen($_POST['direction']) >= 1 &&
        strlen($_POST['phone']) >= 1 &&
        strlen($_POST['password']) >= 1
    ) {
        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $direction = trim($_POST['direction']);
        $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
        $fecha = date("D/M/Y");
        //AQUI VAMOS A INSERTAR LOS DATOS EN LA BASE DE DATOS SEGÚN LOS VALORES
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO datos(nombre,email, direccion, telefono, contraseña)
            VALUES('$name', '$email', '$direction', '$phone', '$password', '$fecha');";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta, 'INSERT INTO datos');
        if ($resultado) {
            ?>
            <h3 class="success">Registro completado</h3>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <h3 class="error">Ocurrio un error</h3>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        ?>
        <h3 class="error">Llena todos los campos</h3>
        <?php
    }


}

?>
```

Comment: Tu código tiene errores de sintaxis. Por favor, mirar la documentación de [Mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) para escribir correctamente las instrucciones. Por otro lado, en la consulta no coinciden la cantidad de columnas con los campos que tratas de insertar. El formato de la fecha generada está mal, no da error, pero no te va a servir para nada; mirar la documentacion de [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). Finalmente, no usar tildes ni `ñ` en los nombres de tablas y columnas.

Answer (score 0):

La línea 22 tiene un parámetro que es equivocado. En lugar de

`$resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta, 'INSERT INTO datos');`

debe ser

`$resultado = mysqli_query($conex, $consulta');`

Adicionalmente tienes otros errores que deben ser corregidos: en la consulta estas enviando un valor de fecha pero no defines el campo de la tabla al que lo enviarás, el formato de la variable fecha debe ser 'Y-m-d' (o 'Y-m-d H:i:s' si tu columna fecha es de tipo datetime). Estas guardando una clave en texto plano (debes usar la función `password_hash()` para ello) y la forma en que verificas que todos los datos existan no es correcta (Si coloco un punto en todos los campos pasará la regla de strlen >= 1)